# C program for anagrams how to (ignore uppercase letters)

Tags: c, string

My program is working fine, and it's just a small suggestion that I need; first here's my code to check if two words are anagrams; It works fine;

```
#include <stdio.h>

int anagram_check(char [], char []);



int main()
{
   char word1[100], word2[100];
   int check;

   printf("Enter a Word\n");

   gets(word1);

   printf("Enter another word\n");
   gets(word2);




check = anagram_check(word1, word2);

   if (check == 1)

      printf("\"%s\" and \"%s\" are anagrams.\n", word1, word2);
   else

      printf("\"%s\" and \"%s\" are not anagrams.\n", word1, word2);

   return 0;
}

int anagram_check(char word1[], char word2[])
{
   int first[26] = {0}, second[26] = {0}, i = 0;

   while (word1[i] != 0)
   {
      first[word1[i]-'a']++;
      i++;
   }

   i = 0;

   while (word2[i] != 0)
   {
      second[word2[i]-'a']++;
      i++;
   }

   for (i = 0; i < 26; i++)
   {
      if (first[i] != second[i])
         return 0;
   }

   return 1;
}
```

Now the question I have is how do I get my program to treat uppercase letters as lower case letters? 
eg. when I enter hello and Hello, it says the words are not anagrams. So how can I change this.

also where it says "second[word2[i]-'a']++;"  what does the 'a' stand for/ or do?

I am also required to ignore any characters which are not letters, and this is already the case with my program correct?

thanks, any help is appreciated!!

Comment: "My program is working fine..." -- clearly, if you don't know what it does, it's not *your* program.

Comment: use `tolower` and `isalpha` of `<ctype.h>`

Comment: Lucky for you, I recently just wrote an anagram/word finder in C. Have a blast: https://github.com/PCLuddite/scramble

Answer (score 3):

First of all, remove the c++ tag from your question.  c and c++ are not the same.  You are writing c.

Also, if you're wondering why you are getting downvoted and people are being a little harsh, let me explain.  This site is usually not friendly to people who ask questions without first showing that they have tried hard to work on a problem.  We aren't trying to be **mean**.  Questions like this one are downvoted to deter more like this popping up.  We aren't here to spoonfeed.

[image: spoonfeeding]

I would suggest writing a small function that converts a character to lowercase, and then calling it in these loops.  There is the tolower function, but I think it would be a good practice exercise to write your own.

```
while (word1[i] != 0)
{ 
   //you should call your function here
   first[word1[i]-'a']++;
   i++;
}
//....
while (word2[i] != 0)
{
   //you should call your function here.
   second[word2[i]-'a']++;
   i++;
}
```

I will not be any more specific because this sounds like a homework problem.

"also where it says "second[word2[i]-'a']++;" what does the 'a' stand for/ or do?"
The 'a' here represents the [ascii code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) for the letter a.  The C compiler will treat 'a' like the constant number 97.

You should think a little harder about what will happen when a non-alphanumeric character is processed.  I will discuss with you in the comments.  Hint: something bad will happen in one of these 2 loops:

```
   while (word1[i] != 0)
   {
      first[word1[i]-'a']++;
      i++;
   }
   //...
   while (word2[i] != 0)
   {
      second[word2[i]-'a']++;
      i++;
   }
```

Comment: Thanks appreciate it. just a few things:
1. with regards to ignoring non -letters, the program already does that eg. hello and hello123 will give 'anagrams' as the reply. SO i don't think that's the problem.

2. how can I use the tolower function? 


Please note guys, I am very new to learning C, (5 weeks in)
Thanks

Comment: If you do try that, this program will overwrite memory, either elsewhere in your program space, or will segfault.  Valgrind will let you know, for character '1', you are writing to the array index of 'first' with the index of '1'-'a', which is 49-97, or `first[-28]++` -- if it isn't crashing you are simply lucky up to now.